# Getting the full .NET type name in codesmith

Tags: c#, codesmith

Is there any way of getting the full .NET type name when writing a codesmith template? GetCSharpVariableType seems to return aliases only. Since I'm using reflection, I need to be able to generate attributes with the type name and just "int" or "string" will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, that method is using the DbType-CSharp map. You would need to create a method in your template that uses the Sql-System map or just use column.SystemType.Name

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski